# MariaDB's `JSON_LENGTH` - alternative for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, mariadb

I need to convert some queries written for MariaDB to PostgreSQL syntax. Unfortunately they use the `JSON_LENGTH` function of MariaDB and im struggling to find an alternative with PostgreSQL.

*For clarification:*

`JSON_LENGTH` counts the number of 'entries' on the root level of a JSON object/array in MariaDB:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_LENGTH('{"test": 123}') as test1, -- 1
    JSON_LENGTH('"123"') as test2, -- 1
    JSON_LENGTH('123') as test3, -- 1 
    JSON_LENGTH('[]') as test4, -- 0
    JSON_LENGTH('[123]') as test5, -- 1
    JSON_LENGTH('[123, 456]') as test6, -- 2
    JSON_LENGTH('[123, {"test": 123}]') as test7; -- 2
```

*Partial solutions in PostgreSQL I came up with:*

```sql
select
    json_array_length('[]'::json) as test1, -- 0
    json_array_length('["a"]'::json) as test2, -- 1
    length(json_object_keys('{"a": "b"}'::json)) as test3; -- 1
```

- `json_array_length` is not allowed for JSON objects
- `json_object_keys` is not allowed for JSON arrays

Unfortunately I can't manage to combine the two methods I figured out for PostgreSQL:

---

*I tried to use `CASE WHEN`:*

```sql
select
    case
        when json_typeof('["a"]'::json) = 'array' then json_array_length('["a"]'::json)
        when json_typeof('["a"]'::json) = 'object' then length(json_object_keys('["a"]'::json))
        else 0
    end;
```

**Error:**

```
[0A000] ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
```

-> `json_object_keys` is the bad guy here

---

*I tried `IF ELSE`:*

```
select
    IF ('array' = json_typeof('["a"]'::json)) THEN json_array_length('["a"]'::json)
    ELEIF (json_typeof('["a"]'::json) = 'object') THEN length(json_object_keys('["a"]'::json))
    ELSE 0;
```

**Error:**

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "THEN"
```

I can imagine I have an error in my `IF ELSE` statement, but I'm unable to figure it out.

---

Is there any way to replicate MariaDB's `JSON_LENGTH` behavior with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the number of rows returned by jsonb_object_keys():

This:

```
with data (input) as (
values
    ('{"test": 123}'::jsonb),
    ('"123"'),
    ('123'),
    ('[]'),
    ('[123]'),
    ('[123, 456]'),
    ('[123, {"test": 123}]')
)
select input, 
    case jsonb_typeof(input)
        when 'array' then jsonb_array_length(input)
        when 'object' then (select count(*) from jsonb_object_keys(input))
        when 'string' then 1
        else 0
    end
from data
```

returns:

```
input                | case
---------------------+-----
{"test": 123}        |    1
"123"                |    1
123                  |    0
[]                   |    0
[123]                |    1
[123, 456]           |    2
[123, {"test": 123}] |    2
```

Of course this can easily be put into a function:

```
create or replace function my_json_length(p_input jsonb) 
  returns int
as
$$
select case jsonb_typeof(p_input)
         when 'array' then jsonb_array_length(p_input)
         when 'object' then (select count(*) from jsonb_object_keys(p_input))
         when 'string' then 1
         else 0
       end;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

I would not name it `json_length()` to avoid any clashes in case Postgres decides to implement such a function in the future (although I am not aware of such a function in the SQL standard).

---

Note that `jsonb` is the recommended data type to store JSON values in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the `jsonb` hint. 

What is the reason to prefer `jsonb` over `json`?

Comment: @gabelbart: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy assumptions about ordering of object keys*" - jsonb supports much more operators and functions than `json`, e.g. anything using JSONpath  expressions.

Comment: Ok, in this case the 'legacy' point probably counts. Im dealing with a third party package that expects the column to be `json` I'm not sure if it can deal with `jsonb` but I will investigate tomorrow. Sorry for not accepting your answer right now, I want to run some final tests on that migration and didn't find the time today. I will check back tomorrow.

Comment: @gabelbart: the "legacy" refers to applications that expect the keys in a specific order (although in theory that is irrelevant in JSON)